# Using webpack with non-js entry point

Tags: javascript, php, webpack

I am working on a data-driven PHP project that has lots of javascript (about 15 different .js files) dependencies. My goal is to minify and concatenate all these javascript files into one bundle.js file - making updates to specific javascript dependencies as simple as possible.

Note, all my javascript files are contained within assets/js and I am trying to output a single bundle.js file in the project root / or dist/bundle.js

I've been looking into using webpack which seems to require a .js entry point which I do not have.

What would be the best way to setup webpack under these circumstances?

Thanks in advance

This is what my package.json looks like now:

```
{
  "name": "my-theme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack assets/js/ dist/bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an entry point file.  For example `index.js`.  Inside your `index.js` you would import your other files.

```
import 'a.js'
import 'b.js'
import 'c.js'
```